# How to apply filter in vba for a sharepoint list

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I have below code using which I am importing huge number of rows from sharepoint list into Excel destination using VBA.

```
Worksheets("ActivityProgress").ListObjects.Add SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
 Source:=Array("http://teamroom.xyz.com/Global/Management/_vti_bin", _
 "Activities", "{926363F0-20C4-4955-8172-96970AF15D9B}"), _
 LinkSource:=True, Destination:=Worksheets("ActivityProgress").Range("A1")
```

Unfortunately, I cannot work on destination after this import due to the huge rows after being imported to excel.

I have a field named ActivityDate (which I need to filter, containing 2015 year data).

Could you please help me with vba on how to apply filter for the Sharepoint List "Activities" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "work on destination" ?

Comment: Hi Cody, Excel file is the destination.. it gets struck when I do any modification .. like applying simple concat formula etc.,

Comment: You only have 2015 rows and it is getting stuck?

Comment: Share a portion of your data (a few rows) and tell us how many rows you actually have (so that we can copy/paste it into that many rows), and the formula you're trying to apply so that the error can be reproduced.

Comment: Am sorry for not being clear with the description.. it is 2015 year data.. (rows related to ActivityDate for the year 2015)

Comment: Have you tried looking into using "PowerQuery"? It is an add-in for excel older than 2016. For 2016 it is built in. Power Query may help you pre-filter your data so that you're not trying to work with so many rows. If you have filled all the rows in your excel sheet then you may need to do that.